# Laravel 6 passport on docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I try to build API inside docker container that connectiong with external(not in container) MSSQL server 2015. I got error when trying to run `php artisan passport:install` on docker bash.

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: Error code 0x2746 (SQL: insert into [oauth_clients] ([user_id], [name], [secret], [redirect], [personal_access_client], [password_client], [revoked], [updated_at], [created_at]) values (?, Laravel Personal Access Client, t4KxVN7GyT3bY8RKAKuHLasIOHnuDbg2FIIVnG4g, http://localhost, 1, 0, 0, 2020-09-25 04:21:16.145, 2020-09-25 04:21:16.145))
```

what i noticed is that the value for [userid] is '?', can this be the cause ?

My laravel .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=10.105.12.12
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=API
DB_USERNAME=admin1
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.4.1-apache

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libpng-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    zip \
    curl \
    unzip \
    gnupg2 \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-source delete


ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y

# Microsoft SQL Server Prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list \
        > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        locales \
        apt-transport-https \
    && echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen \
    && locale-gen \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install \
        unixodbc-dev \
        msodbcsql17

RUN docker-php-ext-install mbstring pdo pdo_mysql \
    && pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv xdebug \
    && docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv xdebug




COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html \
    && a2enmod rewrite
```

My Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services: 
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
    image: 'apidev'
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

i run my docker destop for windows 10

this app is running well if not inside a container

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by changing pdo driver.

instead of using "pdo_sqlsrv" driver to connect to MSSQL 2005, i'm using "pdo_dblib"

hope this helps others